# Is it possible to run after rebooting process a python script that has camera feature in RPI?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, camera, reboot

`
model = load_model("model", compile=False)
class_names1 = open("labels.txt", "r").readlines()

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(2)`

This is my code and I need help on how to autostart this script after rebooting process

Comment: After rebooting what process? Have you had a look at scheduling tasks with crontab?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.